# Scan with Color Invert QR code doesn't work well in Android with ZXing

Tags: android, zxing

I want to scan scan QR with ZXing library and after hours of research, I find this library and it works like a charm.
https://libraries.io/github/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

It also reads inverted qr code well, but doesn't read this qr code.
http://prnt.sc/dijmc8

I'm not sure why it doesn't read only this qr code.

Is there anybody who can read qr code with app which is coded with ZXing library(I can read this qr code well with iOS)?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you found any solution?

Answer (score 4):

I face same issue after change color for it works for me.
If possible then can you change the color for QR code and then try to read QR code.
color to set, Background as White color and QR Code as Black Color.

Answer (score 2):

After trying everything available on the internet, I found this solution-

In your `onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)` function, add the below code.

```
toInvert = !toInvert;

if (toInvert == true) {

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

data[i] = (byte) (255 - data[i]);

}

}
```

Also, initialize the `Boolean` variable toInvert as either true or false in your class scope.

This addition to your code will scan the image with normal scanning as well as inverted scanning and `onPreviewFrame` function will return the result as soon as it finds it.

Comment: [flag] Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately this post does not provide an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question.